# How to make the following query in Django?

Tags: django, django-queryset

I have a bunch of users in a group. I also have a OneToOne relation with each user to a `Profile` model.

I am trying to get all the users who are **teachers** in a specific **school**.

I have a `Teacher` group so I filtered the users with

```
teachers = User.objects.filter(groups__name='Teacher')
```

The following is the profile model.

```
class Profile(TimeStamped):
    user = models.OneToOneField(User)
    school = models.ForeignKey(School, blank=True, null=True)
```

Let's say the instance of the school that I am trying to filter on is assigned on a variable called `school`.

How can I now put a second filter on the `teachers` variable to find the teachers of ONLY a specific `school`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Queryset filters can be [chained](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.10/topics/db/queries/#chaining-filters).

> The result of refining a QuerySet is itself a QuerySet, so it’s
>   possible to chain refinements together.

```
teachers = User.objects.filter(groups__name='Teacher').filter(profile__school=school)
```

It's also possible to add to conditions inside the filter

```
teachers = User.objects.filter(groups__name='Teacher',profile__school=school)
```

Update to clarify point raised in comment

This sort of thing works because foreign key looks works, backwards too. To quote from the manual:

> It works backwards, too. To refer to a “reverse” relationship, just
>   use the lowercase name of the model.

The original query you used referred to the group table this way.

Comment: The User model doesn't have any field called `profile` but the Profile model has a field called `user`. Is the above query going to work?

Comment: Thanks. I didn't know that I can address a model if it was not assigned to a field as a relation.

Comment: glad to have helped